# Check if file is json loadable

Tags: python, json

I have two types of txt files, one which is saved in some arbitrary format on the form

```
Header
key1 value1
key2 value2
```

and the other file formart is a simple json dump stored as

```
with open(filename,"w") as outfile:
    json.dump(json_data,outfile)
```

From a dialog window, the user can load either of these two files, but my loader need to be able to distinguish between type1 and type2 and send the file to the correct load routine.

```
#Pseudocode
def load(filename):
    if filename is json-loadable:
        json_loader(filename)
    else:
        other_loader(filename)
```

The easiest way I can think of is to use a try/except block as

```
def load(filename):
    try:
        data = json.load(open(filename))
        process_data(data)
    except:
        other_loader(filename)
```

but I do not like this approach since there is like a 50/50 risk of fail in the try/except block, and as far as I know try/except is slow if you fail.

So is there a simpler and more convenient way of checking if its json-format or not?

Comment: "as far as I know try/except is slow if you fail." -- compared with reading a file from disk? It really isn't.

Comment: Python exceptions aren't particularly expensive, and in any case this sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: True, the speed is not the real problem in this case but rather the use of the try/except. I read up on try/except and saw this comment http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp where it says that try/except is actually encouraged in Python so perhaps my code is fine as it is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the top-level data you're dumping is an object, you could check if the first character is `{`, or `[` if it's an array.  That's only valid if the header for the other format will never start with those characters.  It's also not foolproof because it doesn't guarantee that your data is well formed JSON.

On the other hand your existing solution is fine, much more clear and robust.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
def convert(tup):                                                               
    """                                                                            
    Convert to python dict.                                                        
    """                                                                            
    try:                                                                           
        tup_json = json.loads(tup)                                                 
        return tup_json                                                            
    except ValueError, error:  # includes JSONDecodeError                          
        logger.error(error)                                                           
        return None 


converted = convert(<string_taht_neeeds_to_be_converted_to_json>):
if converted:    
    <do_your_logic>
else:
    <if_string_is_not_converteble>
```